# Redirect to a URL in chrome packaged APP

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am using multiple authentication providers and protocols(Oauth2, Open ID 2, SAML) for authentication which need client to be redirected to providers authentication URL. After successful authentication server will redirect client back to application server URL with user information/code/token in header.

This is already working fine in web browser, node webkit app and cordova as I can use window.open and then see the changes in the url or close the popup window after getting the access token.

Since this is not an extension I will not be able to use chrome.tabs.  I tried chrome.window also and it also doesn't allow redirection.

Even webview allows to open an external url, but doesn't allow redirect.

I can't use chrome.identity as its just specific to Oauth 2. Sandbox also doesn't work.

Can someone please tell me if they have ever used Oauth, OpenID, SAML, redirections in chrome packaged apps without using the chrome.identity

Comment: Can't help you with OpenID or SAML, but I have successfully used chrome.identity with Oauth1. It's not nearly as simple as using it with Oauth2, as you first have to get a request token and get it authorized. But, once you do that, chrome.identity can cause the website's authorization page to appear so the user can sign in and authorize the app.